# iOS jumps and targets new field when using the autofocus

Tags: javascript, ios, html

I have a login page that contains the usual email and password fields, as well as a log in button. For usability, the autofocus HTML5 attribute has been used on the email field.

When loading the page on iOS, you can tell by the green border that the field has the focus, but because of iOS limitations, the focus is not fully applied to the field, as you can see here with the keyboard not being displayed:

[image: Page load]

The first thing the user does is touches the email field, but as far as iOS is concerned, you're clicking on a different part of the page. The focus is actually given to the password field instead, because the page shifts upwards to make way for the keyboard that did not display previously:

[image: After touching email]

In a similar behaviour, if the user touches on the password after page load, the log in button is clicked instead and validation errors appear.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: The switching focus things smells like it could be from an erroneous `label` tag, or perhaps a JS listener

Comment: Eventually began stripping out HTML until it stopped doing it. Only once I removed the Optimizely JavaScript reference did it cease. I have raised an issue with them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not disable the autofocus when you show the page on iOS?
It would be very annoying when user enter a website and the keyboard pops up without any actions on the page.
I even can't think of any website popping up the keyboard on the load.

Comment: Safari doesn't support autofocus for that reason, which is why this was very confusing.